# QDoppelganger (clone a QWidget into another container)

Tags: pyqt4, qwidget

Overflowers: We have a complex dock widget with several complex, aggregate QWidgets in it.

I need to allow users to minimize the dock widget down to a ribbon (as a QToolBar), containing only the most important widgets. But because these widgets are rather complex, I would rather not reproduce them in code, and painstakingly transfer their custom values back and forth. Clicking one copy of a widget should behave exactly the same as clicking another.

So it seems I would like to invent a QDoppelganger widget, which delegates input and render events back and forth, to make a functioning copy of another control:

```
class QDoppelganger(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, dupeMe, parent):
        super(QDoppelganger, self).__init__(parent)
        self.dupeMe = dupeMe

        formerResizer = self.dupeMe.resizeEvent

        def resizeMe(qResizeEvent):
            self.setFixedSize(self.dupeMe.size())
            return formerResizer(qResizeEvent)

        self.dupeMe.resizeEvent = resizeMe

        formerPainter = self.dupeMe.paintEvent

        def paintMe(qPaintEvent):
            self.update()
            return formerPainter(qPaintEvent)

        self.dupeMe.paintEvent = paintMe

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, qMouseEvent):  return self.dupeMe.mouseMoveEvent(qMouseEvent)
    def mousePressEvent(self, qMouseEvent):  return self.dupeMe.mousePressEvent(qMouseEvent)
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, qMouseEvent):  return self.dupeMe.mouseReleaseEvent(qMouseEvent)

    def paintEvent(self, qPaintEvent):
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap(self.dupeMe.width(), self.dupeMe.height())
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(pix)
        self.dupeMe.render(painter)
        painter.end()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawImage(0, 0, pix.toImage())
        qp.end()
```

Its driver code is trivial:

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton('dupe me')
doppel = QtUtil.QDoppelganger(button, None)
```

Stick one widget into the dock widget, and another into the QToolBar, and we are done.

If I have nailed it, then this post is a useful snippet.

If not, may I request a review of the techniques? No matter how few lines of PyQt code I write, it seems someone always comes along with some "cleverSignal.connect(cleverSlot)" to simply plug things together with even fewer lines of code. Specifically, instead of rendering one control into a QPixmap, then painting that into the doppelganger control, can't I simply connect the paint event directly?

Comment: Add this line to enable transparent backgrounds: pix.fill(Qt.transparent)

Comment: It turns out this code is indeed causing a bug. The line self.dupeMe.render(painter) causes the donor control's container (which is setVisible(False)) to blot out its screen area with a white region. So now the question is: How to call .render() on a control in a container who is invisible, without side effects? While the Qt community ponders this, I will be playing with the z-order...

Comment: Why can't you just use one dock widget and hide some of its children when user wants to minimize it? I think this events magic makes the solution overcomplicated.

Comment: Short answer: Because the layout would still be wrong. Long answer: Because the controls that go into the toolbar come from the "highlights" of several different panels which, in turn, come from plugable modules. Cutting those panels up into pieces, just to appease the toolbar, would scramble a lot of code, where simply poaching the appearance and behavior of specific controls simplifies everything.

Comment: the secret is put QDoppelganger on both the donor & recipient.